# how to add responsive vertical space between columns bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, whitespace

Is it possible to add blank vertical space between columns in bootstrap 3 other than spacer classes with fixed pixels? Fixed pixels are not good if you are going for a responsive site.

Comment: What's wrong with [`offset`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)?

Comment: @ryan-salmons Did you find a good solution here? I've looked around and to me it looks like there's still no simple concept for responsive vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Add extra class to `row` and give appropriate margin

HTML

```
<div class="row container">
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Wont that come out unproportional for mobile browsers? Is there a way to add spacing based off of a percentage?

Comment: If you wish you can also add % value or @media for mobile browsers